# When needing to authenticate a client, use a long-term token or store username and password encrypted?

Tags: authentication, encryption, hash

I'm making an parental application and I need the client (Windows Service) to update with the server every X seconds/minutes. For obvious reasons, I cannot have the user enter the password every time the client needs to update with the server, so I was wondering whether it would be better practice:

- To send the username + password once, and get a token that doesn't expire until a new one is issued or
- Store the username and password encrypted on the client computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a token for authentication is always better that username+password because if someone manages to get access to the saved credentials (token or password) the damage by a revealed password is always higher that by a token that is random and is only used by your service and that can be replaced at any time.

Additionally humans tend to reuse passwords, which means a reveled password would raise security problems in more than just your service.

In my opinion OAuth2 is a good example of a token based authentication system: It has two types of tokens: refresh and access. The access token is like you have described and the refresh token allows to generate a new access token and invalidates the previous access token. This makes it possible to "update" the access token e.g. every week or month.